# Devexpress AspxDateEdit control not getting displayed in the jquery modal dialog

Tags: devexpress

The devexpress aspxDateedit control is not getting displayed in the modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test how the ASPxDateEdit works in conjunction with the jquery modal dialog.  Instead, I suggest that you  use the ASPxDateEdit on the [ASPxPopupControl](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Popup/) which can also be shown as a modal dialog.

In this case, everything will work correctly.